# PHP: How do I get the URL a file is in?

Tags: php

I can't seem to find a super-global for this. Basically, if a PHP file is executed on, say, `http://www.example.com/services/page.php`, I would like to retrieve `http://example.com/services`. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can abuse [`dirname`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php):

```
<p>
<?php echo $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . dirname($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]) ?>
</p>
```

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [`$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` and `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php). `HTTP_HOST` would contain the host name the resource was requested from an `REQUEST_URI` URI path and query that was requested.

Answer (score 0):

```
$scheme = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on')  ? "https://" : "http://";

echo $scheme . str_replace(basename(__file__), '', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
```